F#/VS2022 - Can I make the default module name in new .fs files include the namespace?
In F# in Visual Studio 2022, when I Add (Above/Below) -> New Item -> Source File and give it a name (e.g. "FileName"), it is created with this default text:
module FileName
I would like it to default to text that contains the namespace, e.g.:
module ProjectName.FileName
What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

What you're trying to do should be explained in the documentation. Take a look here, for example.

@Foxy -- I understand how to define the first line of a file as a module, namespace, or qualified module/namespace. I'm looking for a way to specify which one the editor uses by default, as exists for many options in Visual Studio.
